# ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: hadoop, hive, datastax

As I have 5 node cluster with 1 Hadoop node in DSE. I 'm trying to execute Analytics with HiveQL on `Hiveserver2` thru `JDBC` connection remotely. After every `50 /54 jobs` I'm getting error in Hive log:

```
ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - FAILED: Execution Error,
 return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

And after that `hiveserver2` stop making connection. I'm not sure may be `"hive.server2.async.exec.threads = 50"` is the root cause.

Can you please suggest any solution on this error?

Answer (score 0):

in your hive-site.xml you can define how many jobs you can execute in parallel:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.exec.parallel.thread.number</name>
    <value>8</value>
    <description>How many jobs at most can be executed in parallel</description>
  </property>
```

Hope this helps you